# lolminer stops working on a private network at epoch 13

Tags: private-blockchain, mining, gpu

We are using lolminer (v1.67) for GPU mining on our private POW network. The miner was working fine up until we hit epoch 13. When we hit epoch 13, lolminer stopped working on all our NVIDIA GPUs with <=6GB VRAM.

It gave the error `Unrecoverable Memory Error on GPU 0. Reset of all Cuda GPUs required. Please check your (memory) OC & UV settings on this card.`

Things we know:

- Only NVIDIA cards were affected at the time
- All cards affected had between 4GB and 6GB VRAM
- The trigger seems to be hitting epoch 13 (block 390k), but unknown why
- The DAG file at time of error was 1127MB in size
- We were using lolminer v1.67
- Newer versions of lolminer did not fix the problem
- Both Windows and Linux OSes are affected
- The AMD GPUs seem to be unaffected, but all our AMD GPUs have at least 8GB of VRAM
- We use OpenCL drivers for AMD GPUs
- This was a common issue for mainnet Ethereum at about epoch 385 for 4GB VRAM cards (so much later than it's hitting us)
- We ruled out the Ethereum node (Hyperledger Besu in our case) as any source of problem, since the node will run fine on it's own without mining

We have been unable to figure out why this error is popping up in our private network at epoch 13, when the DAG file isn't even 2GB in size. I'm hoping someone else has encountered this issue and can assist.

Part of the problem is we don't know what we don't know. We know we're missing some information, but are not sure what that is. We are unable to use any other GPU miner, as all other miners we have tried switch to mainnet for the dev's mining and then break and are unable to switch back to our network.

Ultimately my question is why are we running into this issue, and how do we fix it? Most of the generic Google solutions relate to mainnet or they expect the network to be much further along before hitting this problem.

Comment: Did you try downgrading to an old version, or using a different miner? I'd report in their github repo, perhaps new changes broke mining old epochs.